# Google spreadsheet editor: reorder script files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

In a google spreadsheet script editor I have several files. I need to reorder the files but can't find a way. Tried to move them with mouse and no luck, and there is no other option to move them up or down.

Is there any way or trick to move the script files up or down?

Here is a sample screenshot, which I would like to move util.gs to the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Currently it's not possible...but you can sort the files alphabetically which you can locate under View tab

Comment: @pnuts it's better than nothing, but not perfect.

Comment: I found your question by chance. Do you want the solution of this your question yet? If you do, how about this tool? I had wanted to rearrange scripts in a project, too. So I created this. https://github.com/tanaikech/ggsrun/blob/master/help/README.md#rearrangescripts If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you still look for the method for reordering scripts in a project using GAS? I have commented about this. But the application I did is a CLI tool made of Golang. So I created the GUI application using GAS. I post the detail method as my answer.

Recently, I found the workaround for rearranging scripts in a project. The flow is as follows.

### Flow for rearranging scripts :

1. Download all scripts in a project.
2. Overwrite the project by one script with the filename which is difference from the filenames of downloaded scripts.
3. Rearrange the downloaded scripts.
4. Overwrite the project by the rearranged scripts. At this time, remove the script ID of each script.

When existing project is overwritten by a script with an unique filename, all scripts in the project are removed and only the file with the unique name is remained. I thought that this can be applied for rearranging scripts.

### Key factor for creating this application using GAS :

When the project is updated, a special scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts` is required. This was required to be retrieved by OAuth2 process. But by recent Google update, the [Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) was added. Manifests made users easily use the script which needs such special scopes.

When above flow is reflected to GAS script, the application is as follows.

[image]

#### IMPORTANT!

> For rearranging scripts, there is one important point. **When scripts in a project is rearranged, version history of scripts is reset once. So if you don't want to reset the version history, before rearranging, please copy the project.** By copying project, the project before rearranging is saved.

Scripts and how to use this are [this repo at GitHub](https://github.com/tanaikech/RearrangeScripts).

Is this useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

By creating new script files, and copy-pasting the content of the old files into those, you can achieve any reordering you'd like. :-)

For example, create 3 new files:

```
file1.gs
file2.gs
file3.gs
```

Copy-paste the content of the old files into those. Write down the old file names somewhere. Delete the old files. Then rename file1.gs, file2.gs and file3.gs to their proper names, using the old file names you wrote down.